# Receive push Noification when application has been force stopped .(Android)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Application which is using Push Notification (GCM) ,This application is receiving Push Noifications when app is running ,but when I forced stopped it from **Settings ->apps->MyApp**(click on it) and click on force stop ,then it is not receiving Push Notifications.
I have tested same with **WhatsApp** it is receiving Push Notifications when  I force stop it .
So how can I implement same with my application .

**Note** : In code I am receiving PushNotifications in a sub class of WakefulBroadcastReceiver ,I have registered it statically in manifest even it is not called when application force stops.

```
public class GCM_Receiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    //Processes Gcm message .
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "GCM_Receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

**Edit** :
I have registered GCM_Receiver statically in this way :

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.myApp.GCM_Receiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RETRY" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.myApp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Edit :** 
And my GCMIntentService code is below :

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService{
//Constructor with super().
public GCMIntentService () {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}
//Processes gcm messages .
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("GCMIntentService ", "GCMIntentService Started");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GCMIntentService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    GCM_Receiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}}
```

Comment: The code you provided is OK, but show how you register your receiver in manifest and what is in GCMIntentService ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BroadcastReceiver not working when I kill my application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946350/broadcastreceiver-not-working-when-i-kill-my-application)

Comment: @ViktorYakunin : I have edited the question ,Plz correct me If I am doing something wrong .

Comment: @ViktorYakunin There is a little bit duplication in that post but it didn't solve my problem .

Answer (score 1):

Only Google Play services, through the `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND` permission, can invoke that particular broadcast receiver. Since I assume that Play services does not include the [FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES) flag when sending the broadcast, your force-stopped application will not receive the messages.

Interestingly, I don't receive any WhatsApp messages after force-stopping the app. Regardless of the app though, if it can receive messages while force stopped, then it definitely receives broadcasts from an intent with the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag.

Comment: In my case WhatsApp receives GCM Pushnotifications even it is force stopped , I have tried this with multiple devices (Samsung , Motorola , Huawei) .

Comment: So how can I set this flag in my case .